# autocomplete function for addresses and suggestion as drop down

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, autocomplete, mapkit

I working with swift 4 for osx and I would like to realize a address autocomplete function like apple maps does:

[image]

How can I do something like the image shows?
I guess the structure will be:

- a simple NSTextfield
- but what is the popup menu? is it a simple popover?

**UPDATE**
Now my app works like this:

[image]

Thats brilliant.
But one little problem:

I write my first character into the textfield, the popover will be shown and the textfield lost the focus. Now I have to click again in my textfield to go on. Is there a way to keep the focus of this textfield?

Comment: It's a TableView in a ScrollView in a popover.

Comment: okay, so my way to do this could be: textfield delegate text did change > open popover with the search string and let them do the suggestions, isn't it?

Comment: Delegate text did change > populate array with propositions, create and show table view in popover, monitor keyDown and tableView delegate to know which row is selected, then replace your textfield content with tableview selection (beware to not trigger the table again when doing that) and close the popover. That's a lot of work but it's worth it, I've done it in a recent app, users like this kind of interaction.

Comment: okay, challenge accepted ! :)

Comment: I updated my first post. one litte problem is there

Comment: Keep the original text field as the first responder. The tableView should not be first responder at all. One way to do this: `tableView.refusesFirstResponder = true`. Then use `keyDown` from the original textfield to know what the user is typing.

Comment: that doesn't work like this way :( explanation: the user write a letter = delegate text did change >  `self.presentViewController(vcPopover, asPopoverRelativeTo: txtfield.bounds, of: txtfield, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .semitransient)
vcPopover.searchString = txtfield.stringValue
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationAutoComplete"), object: nil)` > popover will appear and i lost my focus

Comment: okay it works!! i enable refusesFirstResponder via storyboard - no effect. but with code it works. thanks !!

Comment: Cool. You're welcome. I'm tempted to say: please post your own answer with your working code and the explanation. I think this would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: Yes. There's nothing at all wrong with answering your own question! This site is al about helping everyone, now or down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve the situation like this:

**use the `controlTextDidChange` and present a popover**

```
override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {

  vcAddress.searchString = txtSourceAddress.stringValue
  self.presentViewController(vcAddress, asPopoverRelativeTo: txtSourceAddress.bounds, of: txtSourceAddress, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .semitransient)

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AutoComplete"), object: nil)
}
```

**the popover has a tableview, which gets the suggestions with the SearchCompleter (MapKit)**

```
import Cocoa
import MapKit

class AcAddress: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    var searchString:String?
    var searchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
    var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()


    @IBOutlet weak var tblAutoComplete: NSTableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AutoComplete), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AutoComplete"), object: nil)
        searchCompleter.delegate = self
        tblAutoComplete.refusesFirstResponder = true
    }



    @objc func notificationAutoComplete() {
        searchCompleter.queryFragment = searchString ?? ""
    }

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        searchResults = completer.results
        tblAutoComplete.reloadData()
    }




    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        // FILL IT

        }

    }
```

Comment: I try to update it later - I am not at home at the moment

Comment: I got this :  Exception detected while handling key input. presentViewController:animator:: <popopo.SecondViewController: 0x6000030267f0> has already been presented

Answer (score 7):

I ported the Apple "CustomMenus" example from Objective-C to Swift.  The example includes a search completions dropdown menu for NSSearchField:

https://github.com/dougzilla32/CustomMenus

[image]

Original example on the Apple site in Objective-C:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomMenus

Comment: Sadly this answer which is correct is down voted cause it doesn't give copy paste solution

Comment: Example project for mapkit using custommenus project at https://github.com/xhruso00/MapkitSearchFieldOSX